# why multithreading in c++ reduces the performance

Tags: c++, multithreading

In this code, multithreading is reducing the performance:

```
unsigned long num1 = 0;
unsigned long num2 = 0;

thread myThread1(count1,&num1);
thread myThread2(count2, &num2);

myThread1.join();
myThread2.join();


cout << num1 << endl;
cout << num2 << endl;

 void count1(unsigned long *num1){
long b = clock();

while( clock() - b < 1000)
{
    (*num1)++;
}
}

void count2(unsigned long *num2){
long b = clock();

while( clock() - b < 1000)
{
    (*num2)++;
}
}
```

at last num1 = 690,000 and num2 = 700,000 (num1 and num2 are in this order) but when I run in single thread mode(when I comment the second thread) num = 1,600,000 so multithreading is reducing the performance. why is this happening? by adding a pad between num1 and num2 (64 bytes) the performance gets better but still worse than single thread(num1, num2 = 750,000)

( when the performance is better then the CPU can count more but in the first part it counts 1,300,000 and in the second 1,600,000)

(num1 and num2 are just for counting)

this is the whole code (edited)

Comment: Threads add some non neglectable overhead.

Comment: You are't properly measuring "performance", nor have you properly defined what it is. What is it you expect your code to do and for how long? where is your single threaded code listing for comparison. What are you using to profile it? Provide a MCVE for both cases. We don't have psychic powers to see what you are doing in count1 or count2

Comment: And if this is the declaration of your variables, then you have a bad case of false sharing (if you are doing something like `while true ++*num`.)

Comment: Can't say for certain but this certainly looks like a prime candidate for [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads).

Comment: What do `count1` and `count2` do? I would assume that those simply add numbers but then those wouldn't indicate anything about performance.

Comment: There is ***a lot of missing code*** here for people to comment on the performance of.

Comment: Please show the content of the thread functions.  Threads should have more code content than the overhead of creating and maintaining the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason for the slowdown is that your `num` variables may share a cache line.

In this case, when `num1` is updated by thread 1 on core 1, then the variable has to be also updated on thread 2 on core 2 which will slow down the update for `num2`. And vice versa for `num2`.

And this is considering that you are actually pinning threads on cores (that case also slow down execution).

Try declaring `num1`, pad with 64 bytes and then `num2`.

This would be flagged by a proper profile tool like VTune (now free). This would also measure performance properly.

After reading your thread code, you are really just incrementing your variable for some time (is it `std::clock()`? not the best way to measure performance, especially for multithreading, that's what hardware counters are for, also the loop seems small, you should measure a second for instance), so you probably really have false sharing. Run VTune on your application and check the cache invalidation counter, it should be through the roof.

Comment: While this answer makes sense we can't actually know until the OP shares a MCVE.  It's better to wait until we actually know what the cause is.

Comment: @NathanOliver true, I will keep an eye to update the answer with more details if we get an update.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher how could I pad between two pointers?

Comment: Just add char[64] pad between them. Please also add the [mcve] to get a proper answer, this may be an educated guess, but still a guess.

Comment: There is a possibility that the content of the threads is smaller than the overhead of creating and maintaining the threads.  This would affect performance more than sharing of cache lines; but we won't know until the content of the threads is posted. :-(

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Wholly agree.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thank you for your answer but I don't really understand what do you mean by complete question this is the whole code I have written and I just want to check the performance of multithreading in c++ there is no more code and no more explanation this is just a simple code for testing the performance by seeing the value that cpu can count

Comment: Edited my answer. There are several issues, the time in your loop (1000 is what according to your understanding of `clock`?) and the cache line.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I assume that clock gives the time in milliseconds

Comment: I forget the CLOCK_PER_SEC

Answer (score -2):

Threading doesn't necessarily mean faster, it means they can happen concurrently/in parallel depending on the architecture. There is overhead associated with threads.

Also, it matters what your compiler settings and if optimization is on.

If the function you are trying to running in parallel is fast, then the overhead of threading is going to negate any benefit.

Comment: That's not the real reason. The real reason is the declaration of the variables.

Comment: There is no guarantee that threads will run in parallel.  The OS can schedule the threads on the same processor in serial.